# Dante Server Config

Tags: dante

this is my dante server config:

```
logoutput: /var/log/socks.log
internal: eth0 port = 443
external: eth0
internal: eth0 port = 444
external: tun0

user.privileged: root
user.unprivileged: nobody
user.libwrap: nobody
socksmethod: username
clientmethod: none

client pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect disconnect error
}
pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        protocol: tcp udp
}
```

I want connecet `internal: eth0 port = 443` to `external: eth0` only

And `internal: eth0 port = 444` connecet to `external: tun0` only

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

That would be possible in two different ways:

a) Run two instances of the Dante server, each with their own unique
sockd.conf-file.  In one set external to "eth0", and in the
other set it to "tun0".

Pro: can continue to use Dante completely for free.

Con: some extra overhead, both regarding Dante's resource usage and admin.

b) Use the Dante "Redirect" module (a non-free add-on you can order
at "https://www.inet.no/dante/doc/latest/redirect.html") and
add "redirect from: eth0" and "redirect from: tun0" to
the client-rules matching connections to "internal: eth0 port = 443"
and "internal: eth0 port = 444", respectively.

Pro: no extra overhead or admin work, continues to use one Dante server
instance and one sockd.conf-file.

Con: need to pay for the Dante redirect module, so use of Dante no longer
completely free.